# Como puedo que el largo bottom de un boton sea mas corto que el largo top?

Tags: android-studio, xml

Buenas tardes amigo tengo una consulta, en un boton existe el ancho y alto verdad? 
entonces como puedo hacer para que la parte inferior del ancho(bottom) del boton sea un poco menos que el ancho superior(top) cosa que pueda ver inclinado un poco pero del lado izquierdo si. asi como esta imagen

[image: Boton inclinado]

pero como pueden ver solo en el lado derecho mientras que el lado izquierdo es todo normal sus dos esquinas. espero me comprenda.

la verdad que no he intentado nada hasta ahorita porque no tengo ni idea de como hacerlo en xml peor en java, pero me gustaria mas en xml porfavor.

gracias de antemano.

Comment: Que tal david, mira no he probado esto pero espero te ayude
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13861416/android-custom-shape-button

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, agrega el layout que estas usando. Revisa [ask], saludos.